# What should i do for planning a motion path with a set of values for a robot head?

Tags: ros, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What should i do for planning a motion path with a set of values for a robot head?How to implement the values for motion planning for the joint?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10237/what-should-i-do-for-planning-a-motion-path-with-a-set-of-values-for-a-robot-head?/) by [ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/641/ram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With only 3dof you don't really need a motion planners, just solve for IK. You ca have a look at th solvers provided by KDL, here is a small ref [kdl solvers](http://www.orocos.org/kdl/UserManual/kinematic_solvers).

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1